# Seeking advice on layout options

Tags: java, layout, positioning

I'm currently doing an assignment that involves me creating an elevator simulation. This is currently where I'm at: [image: elevator ui]

The way I've got it working is that when the combo box on the right is changed, the floor lines automatically redraw themselves according to the panel sizes. The tricky part now is I just want to print the floor numbers in the left 'floors' panel, just on top of the floor line. However, I have no idea how to go about it. I toyed with the idea of setting a null layout and positioning the jlabels according to the floor heights (which I have saved in an array). But everywhere I've looked, people have said this is a bad idea.

So could someone suggest a way to accomplish this with a layout manager? Thanks.

Comment: Break it down into manageable chunks, I see, maybe, 10 different panels, each with there own layout requirements...

Answer (score 2):

Start by breaking down you UI into manageable chunks, this will allow you to focus on the individual requirements of each section without getting overwhelmed...

...To start with...

[image]

This would suggest the use of a `BorderLayout`, placing the red section in the `BorderLayout.NORTH` position and the green in the the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position.

...Next...

[image: Header]

The header is broken into (at least) two sections, this would suggest a `GridLayout`...

...Next...

[image: Body]

The body suggest three equal columns, this could be achieved with a `GridLayout` or even a `GridBagLayout`, if you need the widths to be different for each column...

... Next...

[image: Controls]

This is probably the most complex.  To start with the "blue" section would probably benefit from either a `GridLayout`, if the `Number of floors` label and `JComboBox` resided on their own `JPanel` (may be using a `GridBagLayout) or a`GridBagLayout` if you wanted more control

The `red` section is probably a using a `GridLayout`

All three sections would probably be glued together with a `GridBagLayout`...

For example...

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. I have actually got my layout broken into panels similar to this already. But there's definitely some refinements in there that I think will help. Thanks again.